# Does Backand help me convert my angularjs to ionic?

Tags: converters, backand

Im just a student, so please forgive me my poor english, and low knowledge !
Does the Backand help to convert to ionic ?

Comment: Your question is too broad or opinion based. This is not an advice, counseling, tutorials, or code outsourcing service. This is a Q&A site. Please read the "How to ask" section on the Help Center

Comment: What do you expect as answer for this question?

Comment: Im just interesting to know if the backand convert for me.
angular to ionic
and if, someone knows any link that could help in that process, i would very aprecciate.

Answer (score 0):

No Backand does not convert AngularJS to Ionic. Backand is a backend-as-a-service and AngularJS/Ionic are front end frameworks. You would hook your Ionic/AngularJS app to Backand through their REST API to store and retrieve data.